# Remove bathroom faucet cartridge

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge

I  watched numerous YouTube DIY videos on this topic and other articles on the web, they all seem to address the simplest case where you expose the cartridge by remove the faucet top, and turn it with a wrench, and it loosen up relatively easily.

I have an American Standard faucet; when I turn the wrench, the whole assembly turns with it instead of just the cartridge turning.

If I keep on turning, the hose underneath will twist and break off or damage.

If I buy a vice grip, would that help, and where to clamp without damaging the threads?

The old house showed a few tools (screenshot below) but I am new to home improvement and can't figure out which tool will be best for my case.

Can this be done by one person? (I can't hold on to the vice and turn the wrench above at the same time.)

[image: American Standard Faucet]
[image: Underneath]
[image: tools]

Comment: can you reach the valve from under the counter

Answer (score 0):

As @Ruskes suggests, if you can reach and hold that threaded metal part below (use leather work gloves) with one hand, you can use your wrench on the top without having the whole thing turn. That's often a difficult reach.

One way to make it work is to wrap the threads on the under-sink part in a rag to protect them, then lock a vise-grip on there up high enough so the wood of the sink opening cutout blocks the vise-grip handles from turning very far. Then you can use your wrench on top.

Another option is to wrap a cloth rag around the top assembly to protect the threads and finish, and use a large slip-joint or vice-grip plies to hold the outside part of the top assembly from turning while you use a wrench to loosen the center part.